# Find all double comparisons in a C# codebase

Tags: c#, codebase

I recently [learned the perils of comparing double values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46652980/choosing-an-epsilon-value-for-floating-point-comparisons). Now, I want to find all of the double comparisons in our rather large c# codebase so that I can replace them. I've been doing this using full text searches, hunting and pecking through the results, but I'm worried that I might missing something. Plus it takes a long time. Is there a better/smarter way to do this?

In short, I want to find any places in the code where there is a double value on either side of a comparison operator: ==, <, <=, >, >=

should find this if statement:

```
double d = 5
if(d == 0) dosomething;
```

but should not find this if statement

```
int i = 5
if(i == 0) dosomething;
```

Comment: Honestly, just search for "double" and trace the steps.  If you wrote modular code it shouldn't take that long

Comment: Unfortunately, the API we're using exposes doubles extensively. I just ran a search for "double" and it found approximately 500 matching lines.

Comment: do not forget  `var gimme = 0.8d;`  - much luck :)